# Languages that free you from clarifying your ideas

Tags: programming-languages

ok, so is there a [programming language that frees you from clarifying your ideas](http://xkcd.com/568/)?

I couldn't help asking. But if there is one, what would you say comes closest today?

Comment: No. Because you aren't clarifying your ideas for the compiler - you're doing it for yourself... and for other programmers.

Comment: So if you type 'Yawn...' you want the compiler to understand that you are bored and you want it provide you with some entertainment. However, it might also mean that you are tired and want to sleep. You are basically asking the compiler to read your mind. Currently this not supported by any programming language that I know of.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You mean, a programming language that lets you program without explaining what you want the program to do?

No, how would that work? The compiler needs to be told what program to compile.

Digging out an old, somewhat appropriate quote from Charles Babbage:

> On two occasions I have been asked,
>   'Pray, Mr. Babbage, if you put into
>   the machine wrong figures, will the
>   right answers come out?' I am not able
>   rightly to apprehend the kind of
>   confusion of ideas that could provoke
>   such a question.

The compiler can't read your mind. The only way it can create a program to do what you want is to *tell* it what it is you want.

Of course, there are languages that free you from having to specify things that are irrelevant to your overall problem and are only relevant to the underlying implementation. (an obvious example is that most modern languages free you from having to worry about pointers or many other low-level concerns. Many languages also give you ways to iterate over sequences without having to write a manual for-loop. But you still have to "clarify your ideas", you still have to specify what *your* program should do. The best a language can do is free you from clarifying the things that are *not* relevant to your ideas.

Answer (score 3):

That shouldn't be the role of a language, in my view. Instead, the language should *help* you to clarify your ideas, and let you *express* those clarified ideas in as intuitive a way as possible.

Comment: Downvoters: please leave comments to explain your downvotes.

Comment: I upvoted because I found your answer very em ..clarifying.

Answer (score 3):

You could see it from two angles:

- High-level languages like [Prolog](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prolog)
  free you from having to express every
  messy detail of your algorithm. You just
  sketch the high-level picture, and
  prolog fills in the details (e.g.,
  how to do search and deduct the
  answers to your questions, etc).
- On the other side of the spectrum,
  low-level languages like [C](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_(programming_language)) free you
  from having to express your ideas in
  an abstract way. You can just give a
  sequence of very concrete, detailed
  procedural steps (although you can
  optionally introduce abstractions if
  you want to).

So both extremes free you from certain aspects of expressing and clarifying your ideas.

Comment: I would argue that the two extremes you listed free you from "implementing" certain aspects of your idea, not from "clarifying" them. "clarify", in this situation, seems more related to formatting, commenting, variable naming, etc.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think so, but there are a few that prevent you from clearly expressing those ideas - I nominate BCPL.

Answer (score 1):

For various problem domains, there are languages that free you from having to type a lot of stuff **beyond** what's necessary to clarify your ideas. But every language fails in some situations, and for some people. Not everybody is comfortable expressing their ideas in an object oriented design (say, C# or Java), as functions and closures (Scheme), as logical derivations (Prolog -- there are **some** problems for which it fits!), or as declarative statements of the desired result (XSLT, CSS, various DSL's, with varying success) -- yet each of these is the right answer in certain contexts, and most of them overlap to some extent. Indeed, few modern languages are all that purely oriented to single paradigms.

But some languages favour other things over expressiveness: such as having efficient implementations (C), or being easy to learn (say, Python or its scripting kindred).

Answer (score 0):

I hope there isn't a language that frees you from clarifying your ideas. It should be the responsibility of all programmers to do that themselves, not to pass it off to some other person or programming construct.

Answer (score 0):

All good points,  was thinking more along the lines of scripting languages, where you can type away in the debugger until it does what you want (I've done that a time or two for some sysadmin wmi scripts).

Answer (score 0):

Yes, [Whitespace](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Whitespace_%28programming_language%29).